# DreamFactory API - http request format

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, swagger

I'm trying to do a simple **GET** request to my **DreamFactory API**
from a *URL* in the *browser*. But I get the error:

*Role not found.","code":404*

**this is my URL:**

https://df-xxx.enterprise.dreamfactory.com/api/v2/xxx/_table/user?api_key=xxx

I can do **GET** and **POST** request from the ***Swagger*** interface in ***API Docs***, why can't I do it from a simple *URL* in the *browser* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error indicates that no role was found. If you have not assigned a default role to your app (associated with your API key) then you will receive this error.
If you are providing authentication with a session token, and the authenticated user doesn't have a role associated with that app (API key) then you will receive this error.

All calls in DreamFactory require an API key. They also require a role that permits access to the resource specified in the call. The role is determined by the user's user to app to role relationship, if the call included session information, or by checking the default role for the app, if no session info is provided.

A few exceptions:

- User login and User registration calls do not require a role or API
  key.
- Admin sessions do not require an API key. When you use API Docs in the admin console, the system passes the admin session in the background for you.

See wiki documentation here: http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/API